# Java Hibernate: What would be the better design to get rid of casting

Tags: java, hibernate, casting, visitor-pattern

I use Hibernate for persistence.

Suppose I have an entity which contains information about the document and the necessary information for producing it (either printing or sending by email). Just like this:
[image]

The problem here is that DocumentInformation holds reference to abstract class DocumentProductionConfiguration not to the subclasses DocumentPrintConfiguration or DocumentEmailConfiguration.

So when I actually need to get appropriate configuration I have two choices: either use instanceof + casting or use visitor pattern to trick Java so that it would actually understand in the runtime which configuration it is dealing with.

1. Using casting:

   ```
   public class XmlBuilder{
   public XMLMessage buildXmlMessage(DocumentInformation documentInformation){
       if(documentInformation.getDocumentProductionConfiguration() instanceOf DocumentPrintConfiguration){
           DocumentPrintConfiguration printConfig = (DocumentPrintConfiguration) documentInformation.getDocumentProductionConfiguration();
           XMLMessageConfig xmlConfig = handlePrintConfig(printConfig);
       }
    }
    public XMLMessageConfig handlePrintConfig(DocumentPrintConfiguration printConfig){
       ....build that XMLMessageConfig....
    }
   }
   ```
2. Using visitor pattern:

I need to add a new interface for XmlBuilder to implement

```
public interface XmlBuilderVisitor<T> {
    T handlePrintConfig(DocumentPrintConfiguration printConfig);
}
public class XmlBuilder implements XmlBuilderVisitor<XMLMessageConfig> {
    @Override
    public XMLMessageConfig handlePrintConfig(DocumentPrintConfiguration printConfig){
        ....build that XMLMessageConfig....
     }
    public XMLMessage buildXmlMessage(DocumentInformation documentInformation){
        XMLMessageConfig xmlMessageConfig = documentInformation.getDocumentProductionConfiguration().buildConfiguration(this);
    }
}
public abstract class DocumentProductionConfiguration{
    public abstract <T> T buildConfiguration(XmlBuilderVisitor<T> visitor);
}
public class DocumentPrintConfiguration extends DocumentProductionConfiguration{
    public <T> T buildConfiguration(XmlBuilderVisitor<T> visitor){
        return visitor.handlePrintConfig(this);
    }
}
```

Both of these solutions are kinda meh... The first one because it violates open-closed principle (I will need to always maintain these ifs...).

The second one in this sense is better: once you add new configuration, compiler will guide you through the process: first, you will need to implement appropriate method in the configuration itself, then in all the visitor classes. On the other hand, it is pretty awkward that I am basically passing service to the entity...

So I feel like I am treating symptoms rather than the problem. Maybe the design itself needs some changes? But I am not sure how it could be improved...

Comment: Unfortunately your problem is: you use java. Java is far from perfect language and sometime you forced to use some dirty tricks.

Comment: I would use a library that would abstract everything completely away from having to think about such dreary things. I would end up with `objectMapper.toXML(myDocumentInformation);` (as an example) and could concentrate on more important design issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend pushing the "handle" functionality into the `DocumentProductionConfiguration` and subclasses.  So that the `DocumentPrintConfiguration` would contain a `handle` function that builds and returns a `XMLMessageConfig`.  Then your XmlBuilder becomes:

```
public class XmlBuilder{
    public XMLMessage buildXmlMessage(DocumentInformation documentInformation){
        XMLMessageConfig xmlConfig = documentInformation.getDocumentProductionConfiguration().handle();
    }
}
```